# Python location of script if run as .exe from different place on Windows

Tags: python, windows, path, exe

I have a python script:

```
C:\ProgramFiles\myscript.py
```

and have created and .exe version of it using pyinstaller:

```
C:\ProgramFiles\myscript.exe
```

Ive made sure that C:\ProgramFiles is in my environmental windows path, so that I can run the script from command prompt from any location.

Now, the thing is, I want the script to know what is its location. Ive tried some of the available solutions such as:

```
sys.argv[0]
```

or

```
os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

but these solutions only seem to be working while you are working with .py script and python path. Once I switch to .exe and using windows environmental path it doesn't work anymore. So when I run the program from some weird place, like:

```
C:\Users\John>myscript
```

it always assumes that the location where I ran the command from is the location where it is, none of the solutions will give me the result I want - which would be the original location:

```
C:\ProgramFiles\
```

Basically what Iam trying to achieve - I run a command prompt and run an .exe program in it (originally a .py script). Then windows searches its path variable to see if it can find the program someplace visible. And if the windows do find it, then it will be executed. And I want the program to be aware of where have the windows actually found it, not what is the current working directory.

Comment: Maybe `os.path.cwd()`? I don't remember where this function is exactly, but it should be in `os`

Comment: check the documentation - [runtime information](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html) section and especially [this part](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-sys-executable-and-sys-argv-0) with sample script that clears which dir is what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing (thanks [buran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4046632/buran) for his/her guidance), I ended up using this solution:

```
import sys
import os

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    script_location = sys.executable
else:
    script_location = os.path.abspath(__file__)
script_location = os.path.dirname(script_location)
```

which currently seems to be working both for the .py version and the .exe version of the program build by pyinstaller.

The

```
sys._MEIPASS
```

was giving me location in

```
Appdata\Local\Temp
```

which is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following in order to know the folder from which your script runs:

```
import sys, os
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # we are running in a bundle
    bundle_dir = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    # we are running in a normal Python environment
    bundle_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

print(bundle_dir)
```

`bundle_dir` is the folder from which the script is executed. This way your code will work bot when as python script or after being converted to exe.

As I already mentioned in the comment, check [***Run-time Information***](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html) section in PyInstaller docs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the first thing I tried after reading the info you directed me towards was to use `sys.executable` and it worked the way I wanted - it gave me the original location.

Comment: note, when running as `.py` script `sys.executable` will return path to python interpreter. I doubt that is what you want. The way I show guarantees that the same code will work regardless if run as script or after converted to exe.

Comment: Tried the `bundle_dir`, but it seems not to be working the same, as it results in the following output `C:\Users\John\Appdata\Local\Temp\_MEI98882`

Comment: they work the same when bundled. They will differ if you run the python script. If you use `sys`executable` when not bundled in exe you will get the path to python interpreter.

Comment: Yea, `sys.executable` points to the python interpreter when you run as .py, but the whole point of the question was the scenario where you run it as .exe. For the .py approach the solutions of `sys.argv[0]` or `os.path.abspath(__file__)` work just fine. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: The point is that this makes your code universal, no need to have different code for running as py file and different code for the exe. At the moment you need to change your code. And if you use what I suggest, no need to bundle to exe to test.